# For loop with variable increment

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a small shell script and what I want to do when it is run is to display each N'th parameter entered by the user, where N is the first parameter.
Ex: for input `2 3 4 5 6` I should display `3 5`. What I have until now:

```
N=$1
for ((i=2;i<$#;i+=$N))
do
    echo -n ${i}" "
done
```

However, I get a syntax error: operand expected at this part: `i+=$N`.
How can I solve this? If I replace `i+=$N` with, say, `i+=2`, it works. But i want N there...

Comment: Try `((i=i+$N))`

Comment: @Vlad Tarniceru it works like magic! Thanks. Can you also give me a brief explanation why my version doesn't work and yours does?

Comment: Not a problem :) I think yours should also work, try `i+=N`, without `$`.

Comment: What you have now should work, but I suspect you want to print the actual parameter? Try `./script.sh 2 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5`, your script will print out `2 4 `.

Comment: @Vlad Tarniceru Yes indeed `i+=N` seems to work.

Comment: Copied your example. Works alright for me here. Get same output as kos

Comment: I meant it should be `for ((i=$N;i<$#;i+=$N))` if you want to start from the `$N`th parameter.

Comment: @kos, just change the `i=2` with `i=n`.

Comment: @VladTarniceru Yeah, did that already. I forgot to edit the copy-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to get your code work as you wish, you should do something like:

```
N=$1
for ((i=2;i<$#;((i=i+$N))))
do
  echo -n ${!i}" "
done
```

Note the `!` before `i`.

Good luck :)

Comment: Could you explain, in your answer, why all the extra parentheses are required, and what does the `!` do?